# get JSON data from function to give value to Chart JS

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm making a web app and want to draw a chart which values update every 5 seconds. I tried making a global value, but it did not work, because it draws the chart first, and then takes data from my ajax call.

overview_p.php:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    getChartInfo();
});

setInterval(function(){ getChartInfo() }, 5000);
function getChartInfo()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'php/classes/dash/overview_c.php',
        data: "type=stat1&user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseStat1){
            var statHour1 = 0;
            $.each(responseStat1, function(index){
                statHour1 += responseStat1[index].hours;
            });
            $('.statHour1').html(statHour1 + ' uur');
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
   }
```

overview_c.php:

```
      <?php
class Overview{
  public function getStat1(){
                $json_getStat1[] = array('hours' => '2');
            }

            print json_encode($json_getStat1);
        }
    }
}
    $overview = new Overview();
    switch($_POST['type']){
        case 'stat1':
            $overview->getStat1();
            break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: And how exactly is the chart drawn, and what is `.statHour1` here ?

Answer (score 0):

You should draw your chart inside the success function, ajax calls are asynchronous by nature, so the only other alternative is to make the call with async: false , which is a really bad idea (your ui will be frozen untill the server responds).
Also give us something we can work with for a better answer, not much can be understood from what you are presenting